# Shift reduce conflict

Tags: grammar, yacc, context-free-grammar

I am having trouble understanding the shift/reduce conflict problem with YACC. Could someone please break this problem down and explain it to me using the dangling-else example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The dangling else problem basically means that something like:

```
if (x) then if (y) then a; else b;
```

can be parsed as either

```
if (x) then { 
    if (y)  {
        then a;
        else b;
    }
}
```

or as

```
 if (x) then { 
     if (y) 
         then a; 
 } 
 else b;
```

Most languages require the first -- and that's exactly what yacc does, so it's rarely a real issue (in fact, S/R conflicts from yacc are only rarely much of a concern).

Comment: Whether they are of concern you can say only after having understood what it is and why it occurs at a specific point in your grammar. It is really good that LadyMadonne234 tries to understand it.

Comment: @Ingo: Oh, no argument from me on that. I was just noting that (for example) deciding to try to get rid of all S/R conflicts from a grammar is rarely a worthwhile pursuit.

Comment: Thanks, that makes it pretty clear what the issue is. But could you explain how the improved grammar as shown below solves the problem?

`full_if : something
| IF expression THEN full_if
ELSE full_if
;
open_if : IF expression THEN statement
| IF expression THEN full_if
ELSE open_if
;`

So in the stack if you have a statement such as "If A Then If B Then C Else D" - to me it still seems like you have the same problem...i.e. if you are at "If A Then If B Then C" and you see an Else coming, you could still reduce using the first part of the open_if rule right?

Comment: @Lady, to answer this is hard as I think that the grammar you cite is incomplete. AFAIK the dangling else problem can be solved only by changng the language in such a way that, if *if-statement* is some *statement*, one must make sure that betwenn then and else there comes somthing else but a statement, i.e.    if-statement: IF condition block  | IF condition block ELSE block    and block: '{' statementlist '}'